# Is it possible to call a method with a null parameter but have the argument not be null?

Tags: java

In the function below, what can I use to replace `<typedefinition>` to make the program print "O noes!"?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = null;
    story(o);
}

private static void story(<typedefinition> o) 
{
    if (o != null)
      System.out.println("O noes!");
    else
      System.out.println("O yes");
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Maybe reword it or elaborate more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
    private static void story(Object... o)
```

Because if you pass null, is considered as an array (Object[]) of 1 elem (and so != null)

Comment: Did you test it ? That doesn't work.

Comment: @dystroy, can't you tell just by looking at it? (It works).

Comment: I tested it and it print "O yes".

Comment: @jsn. Probably not every one. I am primarily a c developer but found the question interesting. I wasn't aware of this Object... o syntax to indicate an array. So asking to confirm via compiler along with the explanation was a good idea

Comment: Interesting factor is even though you assign Object to o, still it says "O noes!".

Comment: In fact (now that I'm home), I'm using OpenJDK 6. So this is JDK dependant...

Comment: Is this some variable argument syntax? Could be similar to `params`hence why it works.

Comment: @dystroy Did you forget to enter the ellipsis? It makes a big difference. With the ellipsis, the method is of variable arity, so its type is array, not `Object`.

Comment: @dystroy, just curious. Why do some people use OpenJDK, rather than the Oracle JDK?

Comment: @jsn: there was exact same question few hours ago, not sure whether it is closed (or) still open.

Comment: @Nambari I assume you were thinking of [what is the difference between Oracle java and open-jdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642595/what-is-the-difference-between-oracle-java-and-open-jdk). It's now closed as a duplicate of [Is the OpenJDK JVM the same as the Oracle Java SE JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705061/is-the-openjdk-jvm-the-same-as-the-oracle-java-se-jvm).

Comment: So this is the correct answer just as long as you use the not reference closed Oracle JDK ;) (or maybe a new version, I don't know)

Comment: I'd be really surprised if this even compiled in an older version of Java (defined as "older than 1.5" because that's when var-args were introduced). I'd expect a syntax error.

Comment: In fact varargs have been introduced since version 1.5 (toghether with generics, enhanced for, autoboxing...ect)

Comment: I'm skeptical that this doesn't work on OpenJDK 6. There's probably something else going on.

Comment: @yshavit: dystroy is right. My coworker gave it a try and it didn't work for him too.