# Is the java compiler same in all the JDKs?

Tags: java, jls

'javac' is the Java compiler which converts java code(.java) into bytecode(.class).

### According to Oracle

- The compiler accepts source code defined by the Java Language Specification (JLS)
- and produces class files defined by the Java Virtual Machine Specification (JVMS)

Does the same `'javac'` come with all the JDKs like OpenJDK, Oracle JDK or they implement their own `'javac'`?

Comment: `javac` is compatible between all compliant JDKs.  There are different Sun/Oracle versions with different JDK versions, and I think there is at least one "open source" version.  But the code produced by any `javac` version should be compatible with any JVM so long as the target version specified/defaulted on the `javac` command is equal to or less than the version of the JVM.

Comment: OpenJDK and Oracle JDK should be based on the same codebase anyway. I'd wager that there is no difference between the compilers at all, Oracle JDK could just include some non-free classes in the runtime library.

Comment: Now, Eclipse's `ecj` compiler does actually have some notable differences. For one it seems to be capable of emitting (for development purposes) bytecode for source code that only partially compiles somehow, IIRC by replacing the broken parts with stubs that throw an exception. This means it's possible to write (invalid) Java code that (kinda-sorta) compiles but that another compiler will reject completely. (Although this assertion relies a fair bit on playing with semantics.)

Comment: ideally all java compilers should *behave the same*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is same in all the JDKs except for a few minor bugs and changes. `Javac` is not vendor specific, but yes, different compilers can have different bugs in their own implementation and this can cause a slight difference.

So it is possible that a code compiled in one JDK 'may' not compile in the other in the JDK, thus when switching between JDK's it is best to do some rigorous testing  to make sure that everything is working fine

Comment: Any reference stating the same will be a help. Thanks

Comment: These similar posts maybe helpful [link_one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696611/jdk-jre-java-version-confusion?lq=1). [link_two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705061/is-the-openjdk-jvm-the-same-as-the-oracle-java-se-jvm?lq=1). [link_three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find searching, [wikipedia compilers list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#Java_compilers) only have 5 Java compilers listed and of them, Javac is the only one that would be used by the JDKs you listed. Probably IBM's JDK would use their own compiler. I've not find any link or reference for the IBM assumption but it would make sense.

Comment: Last I heard IBM's JDK used parts of the Sun/Oracle JDK, including javac.  But it's been over 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

It tends to be the same Java compiler in all modern JDKs - *but* Eclipse uses its own Java compiler, not the JDK's compiler.

Comment: Any source to back that java compiler is same in all the JDKs?

Comment: No, but the JDK was open sourced as OpenJDK, and anyway, even before that happened, third-party JDKs often found it cheaper to license Sun's implementation and modify it than to write their own from scratch.